# Realm Studio error. Cannot select class as the Realm is not opened

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

So I am trying to add in my classes and properties via the Realm Studio.  When I open my Realm and open my class I am able to add a property of a list of strings.  When I click the plus sign and attempt to add another property, I get a popup with this error :

Failed adding the property named "" to the selected schema:
Cannot select Entities as the Realm is not opened

After this occurs it suddenly shows all my classes have no content.  If I close it and reopen, it shows the classes intact with at least the one property I was able to add.

What is going on here?  Just migrated off the free trial and am on a paid version now.

The screenshots demonstrating this are below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to let everyone know that might have had an issue, it was a bug on the Realm side that has thus been fixed (and quickly).

Thanks Realm team!

Mark